# List of SonarLint rules

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

I'm using Sonarlint to control bugs/code smells from a list of codes, by extracting each output from VS Code and creating some graphs with Python/Pandas. Even though we can find the rules in https://rules.sonarsource.com/c/RSPEC-3936, I couldn't find a list of all code numbers with respective category, be it minor, major etc.

Since we can find rule descriptions like "switch statements should cover all cases (c:S3562), Major" in VsCode itself, I still think it is quite possible to find some sort of CSV/xlsx file which contains that information. Does anyone know if is there any?